# Linked List Stack Implementation - Java

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I have to implement a stack in the form of Linked List for one of my assignments. We have to implement the interface `DStack`, which has the methods `push()`, `pop()`, `peek()`, and `isEmpty()` in our `LinkedList.java` file. The list would take a series of doubles as its content.

What I am still struggling with is basically the `push()` and `pop()` methods for linked lists. I am not sure about the nodes I have made, but here is the code that I have so far:

```
public class ListStack implements DStack{

private Node head;
private int size;


private class Node{
    double d;
    Node next;

    public Node(){
        head = null;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node(double data){
        d = data;
    }
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (head == null);
}

@Override
public void push(double d) {
    if(!isEmpty()){
        Node newHead = new Node(d);
        newHead.next = head;
        head = newHead;
        size++;
    }
    else
        throw new EmptyStackException(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public double pop() {
    if(!isEmpty()){
        double d = head.d;
        head = head.next;
        size--;
        return d;
    }
    else
        throw new EmptyStackException(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public double peek() {
    if(!isEmpty()){
        return head.d;
    }
    else
        throw new EmptyStackException(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

Could someone advise me if I am doing the `push()` and `pop()` methods correctly? If not, where exactly do I need to revise it? I'm looking for explanations online but most of the materials don't really make sense to me.

Also, my teacher forbid us to use any other classes from the Java framework or other class library. Does this mean I cannot use `Iterable` in my code? If so, then creating the additional methods for linked lists such as `remove()`, `next()`, etc. are not needed, right?

I'm still tripping over these linked lists concepts so if anyone could clear this up, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: From a cursory glance, your logic for `push()` and `pop()` looks OK.  Have you tested this code yourself?

Comment: This question is too broad / doesn't have a specific problem statement. Can you please [edit] your question to say **what is going wrong with this code?**

Comment: @Riadiani You should test it first. If after testing, there are some problems you cannot solve, then you may post it here. There are also many sample codes online for implementing stacks.

Comment: @user3437460 the method for testing is still not running (the teacher hasn't discussed it yet), and I haven't found a way to do so. :( I was just worried that I had spent a large amount of time on this and it turns out wrong... thank you though!

Comment: @durron597 I'm not sure if I instantiated the nodes correctly in the heading and the push() and pop() methods, I was wondering if my code was technically correct.

Comment: @Riadiani Perhaps you should try running it first before coming to Stack Overflow and seeing if it seems to be okay.

Comment: @durron597 okay, sorry about that, I will try running it as soon as I am able to. I was just really confused and had no one to ask. Sorry to trouble everyone! And thank you once again!

Comment: I understand that you're confused, programming is tough at first. But, consider the possibility that your code works (it doesn't, `push` has a major problem). But if it did, you could be done without waiting for us to read your code fresh and analyze it. Remember, you want to **help us help you.** Consider the difference between "can you read my code and figure it out" vs. "When I try to push, I always throw an exception but I don't know what's wrong"

Comment: @durron597 understood, and I'll learn from the mistake. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks OK, need to initialize head otherwise push/pop would always throws exception. Consider to throw stack full exception when is not possible instead of empty stack exception.
This would be unlimited list capacity, may be you could consider with a fixed capacity then there would be limitation on push.

Comment: Op checks for null head, and also assigns it as needed. See erick g. Hagstroms answer for the real logic flaw in push

Answer (score 0):

`pop()` and `peek()` look ok, but you shouldn't throw an exception when trying to `push()` on an empty stack. You'll never be able to use the silly thing if that's the case. Instead, you might want to do something different if it's empty, but under no conditions should `push()` throw that `EmptyStackException`.

Comment: Yes, thank you @ChiefTwoPencils. I have corrected it.

Comment: Thank you @Erick G. Hagstrom ! Unfortunately my teacher told me to use EmptyStackException whenever the stack is empty. Maybe the way I coded it is wrong. I will try to figure it out some more. Thank you!

Comment: I fear your teacher misspoke. :-( Or you misunderstood. :-( :-( You can't get around it. You have to allow pushing onto an empty stack.

Comment: @Riadiani Your teacher probably meant to only use `EmptyStackException` when popping and peeking.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already provided advise - it helped me a lot to draw the state of a stack/list for some basic scenarios: At the beginning, in between with a few elements in it and at the end when you delete the last element. And then going through your code step by step and check what happens to the variables and pointers for push() and pop().

Of course that could also be done with the Debugger- but Pen & Paper sometimes clears things up ;) Good luck with your assignment!

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! I will try to do this as well. :)